# PDO Transaction syntax with try catch

Tags: php, pdo, transactions

What is the syntax preferred while using PDO transaction and try catch and Why?

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();
try {

} catch (Exception $e) {


}
```

**OR**

```
try {

$dbh->beginTransaction();

} catch (Exception $e) {

}
```

Comment: Depends on what you do inside the `catch`

Answer (score 3):

The existent answers seem to suggest that since `$dbh->beginTransaction()` could throw a `PDOException` it should be in the same `try` block of the actual transaction code, but this means that the `rollBack()` code itself will be wrong, because it could invoke a `rollBack()` without there being a transaction, which could also throw another `PDOException`.

The right logical ordering of this is that you put the code you want executed in one transaction in one catch block after the transaction has been created. You could also check that the return of `beginTransaction()` is `true` before proceeding. You could even check that the database session is in a transaction before calling `rollback()`.

```
if ($dbh->beginTransaction()) 
{
  try 
  {
    //your db code
    $dbh->commit();
  } 
  catch (Exception $ex) 
  {
    if ($dbh->inTransaction())
    {
       $dbh->rollBack();
    }        
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that you could still, at least in theory, get an exception from `beginTransaction()` and `rollBack()` so I would put this in a separate function and enclose the invocation in another `try-catch` block.

You could also bubble the exception you get up to catch it and log all Exceptions in one place. But remember that some exceptions could be data integrity errors such as duplicate keys or invalid foreign keys, which would not be a database fault as such, but most probably a bug in your code.

With this approach, the main thing to keep in mind here is that the two `try-catch` blocks have a slightly different purpose. The inner one is purely to ensure that multiple queries are executed and committed atomically in one transaction and if something happens they are rolled back. The external `try-catch` would be to detect erroneous situations and log it, or whatever you would want to do if you have a problem with your database.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
} catch (Exception $e) {

}
```

Simply because an exception could be thrown as you attempt to begin the transaction.

Note that you can place another try catch block inside the initial try.

Answer (score 0):

The second one usually makes most sense. Since you may not always know what will cause the transaction to fail, you would want the rollback (and possibly commit) logic available in the catch, so you'd want to put the `beginTransaction()` inside of the try.

In addition to the `try/catch` make sure you set the error mode attribute:

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

And if anything you should catch the `PDOExecption` just because you should not treat all exception in the same way.

```
try {
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    //do stuff
    $dbh->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $dbh->rollBack();
    //...
    throw $e;
}
```

But if you still want to catch other exception add more catch blocks:

```
try {
    ....
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  //handle pdo exception
}catch (Exception $ex) {
  //handle others differently 
}
```